# Create select element with knockout for complex grouped data

Tags: jquery-mobile, select, knockout.js

I have problem with knockout auto binding for `select`.

I want to create `select` for every group of data in my knockout view model.
[This is jsfiddle example of my problem!](http://jsfiddle.net/freshbm/qjUbx/5/)

Basically I have one `ko.observableArray([])` with list of groups of users. I want to create  for every group with users as .

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.userList">
        <select  data-bind="options: Users, 
                            optionsText: 'FullName', 
                            optionsValue: 'UserId',
                            value: 'UserId'">
        </select>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. It works for single array of users and when I use `div` and `ul`, `li` combination, but not for grouped data. I'm clearly missing something, but I can't figure it out.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.userList">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Users">
         <li data-bind="text: FullName"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Above code works fine.

Can anyone help me?

*Update

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419956/jeroen) sad it works when jquery mobile is disabled, but not with it.

Comment: Seems to be that jQuery mobile has something to do with this, if I disable it in your fiddle [things seem to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/qjUbx/6/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your position where you call your code.... quick fix would be loading your js after your html.

http://jsfiddle.net/MvH_MontySCOUT/qjUbx/8/

put your js after your

```
<body>
```